# One line condition check in Makefile

Tags: make

I'm trying to achieve something like this:
If user will run `make build_x version=1.0` then show `Building version 1.0`, else (`make build_x` without `version` param) show `Building version latest`. But what is the key here - I need to version be `-` by default value (to be able to use it properly with `git`). This is why I use additional variable `version_info` for replacing `-` with `latest`.

So my code looks like this:

```
build_x:
    $(eval version ?= -)        
    $(eval version_info = ${if ["${version}" == "-"], "latest", "${version}"})

    ${INFO} "Doing checkout according to version $(version_info)..."
```

I know that probably issue is with this condition given to `if`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of makefile? GNU?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works for me:

```
version ?= -
ifeq (-,$(version))
  version_info = latest
else
  version_info = $(version)
endif

build_x:
    @echo version_info = $(version_info)
```

It sets `version` to `-` if unset, then fills in `version_info` appropriately.

Using target-specific variables, and a one-liner variant:

```
build_x: version ?= -
build_x: version_info = $(if $(version:-=),$(version),latest)
build_x:
    @echo version_info = $(version_info)
```

This works as follows (see the overall [GNU Make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/)):

- `version ?= -` [sets `version`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Setting.html#Setting) to `-` if it’s not already set
- `if` [checks its first argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html#Conditional-Functions), evaluates it to see if it’s empty or not, and is replaced with the second argument if the first is non-empty, and the third if it is
- `$(version:-=)` evaluates `version`, [replacing `-`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) with the empty string (`:` introduces the replacement, the search key is the text before `=`, the replacement is the text after `=`)

Answer (score 0):

You could put the target-specific variable value feature to good use here:

```
build_x: version := latest
build_x:
     @echo "Building version $(version)"
```